# How to use button behaviour inside of scrollview in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to figure out how I could make a label have the properties of a button, while the label itself is scrollable.
I have tried a couple of different things but haven't managed to get it to work, here's my current code, my end goal is to have every number as a separate "clickable" entity, but for now if I could figure out how to make the whole lable have the properties of a button, that would be good enough.

My code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Testime(Widget):

    pass

class loendtest(App):
    tulemus = NumericProperty()
    loend = ListProperty()
    loend2 = StringProperty()
    loend3 = StringProperty()

    def build(self):

        return Testime()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loendtest().run()
```

```
<Testime>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:3
        size: root.size
        Button:
            text: "add a result"
            on_press:
                app.tulemus += 1
                app.loend.append(app.tulemus)
                print(app.tulemus)
                print(app.loend)
                app.loend2 = " " + str(app.loend).strip('[]').replace(',', '\n')
                print(app.loend2.split())
                app.loend3 = " " + str(app.loend2.split()).strip('[]').replace(',', '\n')
                print(app.loend3)
        ScrollView:
            Label:
                size_hint_y: 2
                font_size: 75
                text_size: None, self.height
                valign: "top"

                text:
                    app.loend3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a custom `Label` that acts like a `Button`:

```py
class MyButtonLabel(ButtonBehavior, Label):
    pass
```

... and replace your `Label` with it...

*OR*, you can do that on the `kv` side, like this:

```py
<MyButtonLabel@ButtonBehavior+Label>
```